# Image is not using all the width

Tags: html, css

I defined an image width as 100%, though, when I change to a 320 px display it doesn't use all the width.
[image: Not using all the width]

I tried using vw, putting the exact width size of the display. But it never works, it only works if I put a larger width.

My code is in this Github repository, with html and css files: https://github.com/JoeyBeckWheeler/Projeto-Everest

```
.banner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    background-image: url('../imagens/bg-2.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #878A8C;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  background-image: url('https://github.com/JoeyBeckWheeler/Projeto-Everest/tree/main/Assets/imagens/bg-2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
}

.slogan {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: white 2px solid;
}


/* Talvez eu tenha que arrumar no responsivo */

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.menu-list,
a {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px 15px 0 0;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/*  */

.title {
  margin: 15vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.infos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#Plans-section {
  margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 1vh;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.card-item {
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.subtitle {
  background-color: #3B5159;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#About-Us-section {
  margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: #878A8C;
  padding: 1vh;
  border: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  line-height: 2;
}

.about-title {
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  background-color: #283940;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:375px) {
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right: 35px;
  }
  #Plans-section {
    width: 80vw;
  }
  .images {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Assets/CSS/style.css">
  <title>Projeto</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header class="banner">

    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="menu-list">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="index.html">Início</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#Plans-section">Planos</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#About-Us-section">Sobre nós</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="title">
      <div class="titulo">
        <h1> Corretora Everest </h1>
        <p class="slogan"><b><em>Te ajudamos a chegar alto </em></b></p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>


  <div class="infos">
    <main>

      <section id="Plans-section">
        <div class="card-item">
          <img class="images" src="./Assets/imagens/card_01.png" alt="">
          <p class="subtitle">Plano Star</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-item">
          <img class="images" src="./Assets/imagens/card_03.jpg" alt="">
          <p class="subtitle">Plano Diamond</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-item">
          <img class="images" src="./Assets/imagens/card_05.jpg" alt="">
          <p class="subtitle"> Plano Magic</p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="About-Us-section">
        <article>
          <header class="about-title">
            <h2>Sobre nós</h2>
          </header>
          <ul class="info-text">

            <li style="margin-left:  15px; ;">
              <p>Investimos o seu dinheiro como se fosse <b>nosso</b></p>
            </li>



            <li style="margin-left:15px;">
              <p>Com planos de investimentos personalizados te ajudamos a <b>chegar alto!</b></p>
            </li>


            <li style="margin-left:  15px; ;">
              <p>Nosso time conta apenas com especialistas da área</p>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </article>
      </section>

    </main>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2022</p>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide the html file as well please?

Comment: Look in devtools at it's parent elements, there could be some margin/padding set somewhere

Comment: @MichaelRogers Sure, I linked my github repository with the html file and css.

Comment: add `overflow-x: hidden;` to body. The overflow is caused by the margin in Plans section

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are now banned from margin. Find other ways of spacing elements. Consider using padding and gap instead.

Use `outline: 1px solid red` on everything to find overflowing elements.

Also, avoid setting harsh width/height, especially with viewport units, try using min-height, max-width, etc.

Sign up for Kevin Powell's Conquering Responsive Layouts course.

I hope this example sets you on the right path, stop using CSS to shoot yourself in the foot.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  background-color: #878A8C;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60vh;
  background-image: url('https://github.com/JoeyBeckWheeler/Projeto-Everest/tree/main/Assets/imagens/bg-2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
}

.slogan {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: white 2px solid;
}


/* Talvez eu tenha que arrumar no responsivo */

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.menu-list,
a {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 15px 0 0;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/*  */

.title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.infos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#Plans-section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 1vh;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.card-item {
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.subtitle {
  background-color: #3B5159;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#About-Us-section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: #878A8C;
  padding: 1vh;
  border: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  line-height: 2;
}

.about-title {
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  background-color: #283940;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:375px) {
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right: 35px;
  }
  #Plans-section {
    width: 80vw;
  }
  .images {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Assets/CSS/style.css">
  <title>Projeto</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header class="banner">

    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="menu-list">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="index.html">Início</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#Plans-section">Planos</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#About-Us-section">Sobre nós</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="title">
      <div class="titulo">
        <h1> Corretora Everest </h1>
        <p class="slogan"><b><em>Te ajudamos a chegar alto </em></b></p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>


  <div class="infos">
    <main>

      <section id="Plans-section">
        <div class="card-item">
          <img class="images" src="./Assets/imagens/card_01.png" alt="">
          <p class="subtitle">Plano Star</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-item">
          <img class="images" src="./Assets/imagens/card_03.jpg" alt="">
          <p class="subtitle">Plano Diamond</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-item">
          <img class="images" src="./Assets/imagens/card_05.jpg" alt="">
          <p class="subtitle"> Plano Magic</p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="About-Us-section">
        <article>
          <header class="about-title">
            <h2>Sobre nós</h2>
          </header>
          <ul class="info-text">

            <li>
              <p>Investimos o seu dinheiro como se fosse <b>nosso</b></p>
            </li>



            <li>
              <p>Com planos de investimentos personalizados te ajudamos a <b>chegar alto!</b></p>
            </li>


            <li>
              <p>Nosso time conta apenas com especialistas da área</p>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </article>
      </section>

    </main>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2022</p>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```